# PHPUnit has different behavior for the same code

Tags: php, phpunit, behavior

I'm currently writing unit tests for a mysqli wrapper class that I've written.

One of the tests is to check connecting to MySQL using wrong credentials.

This is the class' c'tor code:

```
public function __construct($host, $userName, $password, $databaseName)
{
    $this->m_sqlConn = new mysqli($host, $userName, $password, $databaseName);
    if( !mysqli_connect_error() )
    {
            //...
    }
    else
    {
        throw new FailedToConnectDatabaseException( $this->getLastDatabaseErrorStr() );
    }
}
```

When I debug my PHP code(with XDebug), no error nor exception are thrown when create new mysqli

(I run this line:)

```
$conn = new MySQLConnection("localhost", "WRONG_USERNAME", "WRONG_PASSWORD", "NON_EXISTANT_DB");
```

but when PHPUnit runs the same code when testing:

```
public function test_wrongCredentials() {
        $this->object = new MySQLConnection("localhost", "WRONG_USERNAME", "WRONG_PASSWORD", "NON_EXISTANT_DB");
    }
```

it reaches the error handler saying

> "mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'WRONG_USERNAME'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

What could be the reason, or there's something which I don't know?

Comment: Do you want us to guess randomly, or are you going to put up some code?

Comment: @DamienBlack added class, php unit, debug code.

Comment: We need you PHPunit code, since that is throwing the error.

Comment: @DamienBlack it's there, look at "public function test_wrongCredentials"

Comment: Is PHPunit creating a mock object for the mysqli class?

Comment: And I'm guessing that MySQLConnection isn't a mock class either?

Comment: @DamienBlack MySQLConnection isn't a mock class too. anyway, I've found a solution for this, I have just added @  to the unit test line so it'll ignore the errors popped out of that line.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting is expected as your code specifically throws it.

The way to deal with this in PHPUnit is to use an [annotation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#appendixes.annotations) to tell it about the 'expected exception'. In your case the appropriate annotation is, strangely enough, [@expectedException](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#appendixes.annotations.expectedException).

So your test should look something like this:-

```
/**
 * @expectedException FailedToConnectDatabaseException
 */
public function test_wrongCredentials() 
{
    $this->object = new MySQLConnection("localhost", "WRONG_USERNAME", "WRONG_PASSWORD", "NON_EXISTANT_DB");
}
```

That should make your test pass without resorting to using the evil @.